# how to edit a sql server profile template using a text editor like notepad or ssms?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, profiler

I am running a trace where I need to filter the behaviour or about 50 users, and some 50 database objects.

I would like, for this purpose to create a sql server profile template and later edit it to add the events I want and the filters I want. How can I achieve that?

I have tried [to save my template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25143864/where-are-the-trace-templates-saved-to), but when I then try to open it using a text editor like notepad I get the result below:

[image]

On the other hand, if from inside sql server profile, I import my template, and use it to run a trace that is fine, but when I want to add my filters I would need to go through a manual process and there are too many filters and each needs to be added individually.

[image]

how can I achieve this by editing the template file?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/modify-a-trace-template-sql-server-profiler?view=sql-server-2014

Answer (score 1):

Set up the trace for one user , start it and then on SQL Profiler File Menu

```
File --> Export --> Script Trace Definition
```

Though it is now recommended to use extended events instead of traces.